# How to select a variable with an input and change its value in python(2.7)

Tags: python

How could I select a variable with an input and than change its value,
this is the best that I could come up with but it doesn't seem to work.

```
itm1 = 1
itm2 = 1
x = raw_input()
x += 1
print (itm1)
```

I'm trying to get it so that anyone of the variables could be changed depending on the input.

Comment: How about defining a dictionary with `itm1`, `itm2` as keys. You can get `itm1` as input and change the values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible, but you really shouldn't do that in most cases. Nicer way is to store the parameters in a dictionary and do something like:

```
d = {
  'itm1': 1,
  'itm2': 1,
}
x = raw_input()
d[x] += 1
print (d['itm1'])
```

If you really need to change the local variables and have a good reason not to rewrite it to a proper collection, you can use this: (but it's fugly)

```
locals()[x] += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

What do you want to do exactly?

If you want to add the input value to an existing variable you can just do this:

```
itm1 = 1
itm2 = 1
x = raw_input()
itm1 += x
print (itm1)
```

Your question is unclear regarding the aim.
If you want to select one variable to change depending on the input, you can try this:

```
itm = [1, 1]
x = raw_input()
itm[x] += 1
print(itm[x])
```

Of course this assumes you're entering a value in the bounds of the aray indices.

Or you can define a dictionary

```
y = {"itm1": 1, "itm2": 1}
x = raw_input()
y[x] += 1
print( y[x] )
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use 'exec'. This takes variable name through raw_input and executes "variable += 1"

```
itm1 = 1
itm2 = 1
exec(raw_input()+'+=1')
print(itm1)
```

But this isn't the best method. Use dictionaries or lists instead

Comment: Downvoted for "should". No - they definitely shouldn't use `exec` unless that's the absolute last resort. :(

Comment: sry, typo, it was supposed to be "could"